# How To Join Two Table and Show Result in Third Table

Tags: mysql, join

I Have Made a Two `Table` (`Quotation1` and `Quotation2`) and It has Following `Columns` Like:

```
CREATE TABLE Quotation1 (
    Q_No      INTEGER (10),
    Date      DATE,
    C_Code    VARCHAR (45),
    C_Name    VARCHAR (45),
    C_Contact VARCHAR (45),
    G_Tot     VARCHAR (45),
    Remarks   VARCHAR (250) 
);

CREATE TABLE Quotation2 (
    Q_No         VARCHAR (45),
    P_Code       VARCHAR (45),
    P_Name       VARCHAR (45),
    Price        VARCHAR (45),
    Qnty         INTEGER (10),
    Amt          VARCHAR (45),
    Discount_Per INTEGER (10),
    Discount     INTEGER (10),
    VAT_Per      INTEGER (10),
    VAT          INTEGER (10),
    Tot_Amt      VARCHAR (45) 
);
```

I have To `Joins` Both These `Table` and Show Its `Result` in `Third Table` `Quotation` Which has Following `Columns` Like:

```
CREATE TABLE Quotation (
    Q_No         INT (10)     PRIMARY KEY
                              NOT NULL,
    Date         DATE,
    C_Code       VARCHAR (45) REFERENCES CustomerInfo (C_Code) ON DELETE NO ACTION
                                                               ON UPDATE NO ACTION
                                                               MATCH SIMPLE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    C_Name       VARCHAR (45),
    C_Contact    VARCHAR (45),
    Remarks      VARCHAR (45),
    P_Code       VARCHAR (45) REFERENCES ProductInfo (P_Code) ON DELETE NO ACTION
                                                              ON UPDATE NO ACTION
                                                              MATCH SIMPLE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    P_Name       VARCHAR (45),
    Price        VARCHAR (45),
    Qnty         INTEGER (10),
    Amount       VARCHAR (45),
    Discount_Per INTEGER (10),
    Discount     INTEGER (10),
    VAT_Per      INTEGER (10),
    VAT          INTEGER (10),
    Tot_Amt      VARCHAR (45),
    G_Tot        VARCHAR (45) 
)
WITHOUT ROWID;
```

I have Applied Following `Query` Like:

```
INSERT INTO Quotation (Q_No,Date,C_Code,C_Name,C_Contact,Remarks,P_Code,P_Name,Price,Qnty,Amount,Discount_Per,Discount,VAT_Per,VAT,Tot_Amt,G_Tot)
SELECT Quotation2.Q_No,
       Quotation1.Date,
       Quotation1.C_Code,
       Quotation1.C_Name,
       Quotation1.C_Contact,
       Quotation1.Remarks,
       Quotation2.P_Code,
       Quotation2.P_Name,
       Quotation2.Price,
       Quotation2.Qnty,
       Quotation2.Amt,
       Quotation2.Discount_Per,
       Quotation2.Discount,
       Quotation2.VAT_Per,
       Quotation2.VAT,
       Quotation2.Tot_Amt,
       Quotation1.G_Tot
FROM Quotation1,
     Quotation2
INNER JOIN Quotation ON Quotation1.Q_No=Quotation2.Q_No;
```

It Gives Following `Result` Like: `[02:16:23] Query finished in 0.010 second(s).`

But Doesn't Show any `Data` Not Even `Column Name` Please Help.

Comment: For starters .. You shouldn't use `Date` to name a field.  It's just bad practice as it's a reserved term used by MySQL.   I doubt it'll affect your query, just pointing out an observation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you joining to your target table when inserting?

```
-- Insert
INSERT INTO Quotation (Q_No,Date,C_Code,C_Name,C_Contact,Remarks,P_Code,P_Name,Price,Qnty,Amount,Discount_Per,Discount,VAT_Per,VAT,Tot_Amt,G_Tot)
SELECT Quotation2.Q_No,
       Quotation1.Date,
       Quotation1.C_Code,
       Quotation1.C_Name,
       Quotation1.C_Contact,
       Quotation1.Remarks,
       Quotation2.P_Code,
       Quotation2.P_Name,
       Quotation2.Price,
       Quotation2.Qnty,
       Quotation2.Amt,
       Quotation2.Discount_Per,
       Quotation2.Discount,
       Quotation2.VAT_Per,
       Quotation2.VAT,
       Quotation2.Tot_Amt,
       Quotation1.G_Tot
FROM Quotation1
JOIN Quotation2 ON Quotation1.Q_No = Quotation2.Q_No;

-- Show results:
SELECT * FROM Quotation;
```

Should do the job.

Comment: [20:54:09] Error while executing SQL query on database 'InventorySystem': UNIQUE constraint failed: Quotation.Q_No

Comment: This tells you, that you have duplicated Q_No in Quotation1 or Quotation2. Most likely because you don't have your constraints there. You can get rid of this error by using `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `INSERT` **BUT** be careful since you'll lose data by doing so.

Comment: Thanks its working i have made changes like `UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE`

Comment: How Can I Run This `Query` On `Java` Any Hint